# ionic configuring push notifications

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to setup push notifications, I'm stuck [here](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/#cloud-configuration), and I have no idea where to put this code:

```
const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': 'APP_ID',
  },
  'push': {
    'sender_id': 'SENDER_ID',
    'pluginConfig': {
      'ios': {
        'badge': true,
        'sound': true
      },
      'android': {
        'iconColor': '#343434'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

P.s `app.modules.ts` doesn't exist in my project

Ionic version: 2.1.4
Cordova: 6.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-push-notifications/

Or you can try wiht OneSignal Push Notfications, they have great documentation...